# how to show image proper format?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I retrieve name and image from database that name and image are come in aspx as the requirement but problem is that image show one line only like "[image][image][image][image]"this format but i want 2x2 image

aspx code :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="reapterclient" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repeaterclient_OnItemDataBound">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                            <table width="645" align="left" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="01" border="0" bgcolor="#252525">
                                            <tr bgcolor="#lclclc" height="40">
                                            <td id="tdcollection" width="50%" align="center" valign="middle" class="general"><asp:Image ID="imgClient" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"~/clients_images/"+Eval("Client_Logo") %>' Visible="true" Height="67" Width="380"/><br />
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblimgClient" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Client_Name") %>' Visible="true"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>


                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2"/>
                                            </tr>

                                            </table>
                                            </ItemTemplate>


                                </asp:Repeater>
```

cs code :

```
public void binddata()
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select Client_Name,Client_Logo from tp_Client_Master where (Project_Type like '%commercial%')",con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds);
            reapterclient.DataSource = ds;
            reapterclient.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: Please take a second, slow down, and *properly* formulate your question before asking the community. Would you want an answer that looks like your question?

Comment: any one is here please it's urgent please

Comment: You can help your own cause by taking George's advice and formatting your question properly, so potential answerers can read the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
<asp:Image 
      ID="imgClient" 
      runat="server" 
      ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Client_Logo","~/clients_images/{0}") %>'
```

Comment: no avd proper format still not coming i want image like one image right and one left same way all

Comment: Does `Client_Logo` store the image format too? Ex: `Client_Logo = "logo.png"`

Comment: @JamesJohnson - If it is byte array (blob) then wont work. I guess the client_logo is varchar and it contains filename with relative path.

Comment: guys im got solution it was done using asp:table but thank you your advice